# Android how to apply customfont to ButtonText

Tags: android, button, textview, custom-font

I have a button in android which has a text in it. I am applying custom fonts to all TextViews in Android using below code :

```
Typeface custom_font_subtitle = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/omnesreg.ttf");
subtitle.setTypeface(custom_font_subtitle);
```

Since button do not have textview, how do i apply the same for it ?

Any suggestion

Thanks

Comment: Look at `Button` docs, it inherits from TextView https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Comment: if friend's answer doesn't work,you can set textView as button with click effect

Comment: @MHP what's wrong with the answers ?

Comment: nothing,below answers should work but I said if you try and doesn't word you can do this

Comment: Thanks a lot guys...All your answers are working...

Answer (score 2):

```
    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/omnesreg.ttf");
    button1.setText("hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this:

```
    Button btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonreturn);
    btn.setTypeface(custom_font);
```

Comment: so can you tick this solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Typeface custom_font_subtitle = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),         "assets/omnesreg.ttf");
subtitle.setTypeface(custom_font_subtitle);
```